Gazebo Crashing cmd 'gzserver -slibgazebo_ros_init.so -slibgazebo_ros_factory.so -slibgazebo_ros_force_system.so']
i’m working on a 2 wheel autonomous robot simulation with ROS2 and Gazebo.
when never I launch this file gazebo sever crashing error
Therefore im trying to setup ros2_control, but i got quiet some problems with it:
My setup:
Ubuntu 22.04
Ros humble
Gazebo 11.10.2
 [INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/rushabh/.ros/log/2024-04-09-13-18-42-594237-rushabh-Aspire-A515-57G-16729
    [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
    [INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [16730]
    [INFO] [gzserver-2]: process started with pid [16732]
    [INFO] [gzclient-3]: process started with pid [16734]
    [INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [16736]
    [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1712648923.094190383] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
    [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1712648923.094275619] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
    [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1712648923.094283079] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_wheel
    [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1712648923.094287323] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment chassis
    [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1712648923.094291022] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment laser_frame
    [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1712648923.094294762] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
    [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1712648923.094298184] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
    [spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712648923.432397658] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
    [spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712648923.432575539] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
    [spawn_entity.py-4] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
    [spawn_entity.py-4]   warnings.warn(
    [spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712648923.434408748] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
    [spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712648923.436421328] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
    [spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712648923.436559657] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
    [spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712648923.942277609] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
    [spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712648924.038296746] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [my_bot]
    [gzserver-2] [WARN] [1712648924.041204362] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=scan'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=scan' instead.
    [gzserver-2] [WARN] [1712648924.043025578] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=scan'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=scan' instead.
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.158360950] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading gazebo_ros2_control plugin
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.159782936] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in namespace: /
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.159882893] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in ros 2 node: gazebo_ros2_control
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.161372760] [gazebo_ros2_control]: connected to service!! robot_state_publisher
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.161642296] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Received urdf from param server, parsing...
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.161672439] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading parameter files /home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/autonomous_bot/share/autonomous_bot/config/my_controller.yaml
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169589329] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: left_wheel_joint
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169639850] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169646771] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169651632] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        position
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169655384] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169671685] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169678662] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: right_wheel_joint
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169682590] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169686182] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169689760] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        position
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169693107] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169697665] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169718250] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'GazeboSystem' 
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169788738] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169830884] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'GazeboSystem' 
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169835732] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169838901] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'GazeboSystem' 
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169842185] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
    [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1712648924.169888943] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading controller_manager
    [INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 16736]
    [ERROR] [gzserver-2]: process has died [pid 16732, exit code -11, cmd 'gzserver -slibgazebo_ros_init.so -slibgazebo_ros_factory.so -slibgazebo_ros_force_system.so'].

robot.xarco
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

        <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
            <hardware>
                <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
            </hardware>
            <joint name="left_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
            <joint name="right_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-10</param>
                    <param name="max">10</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
            </joint>
        </ros2_control>
         <gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
            <parameters>$(find autonomous_bot)/config/my_controller.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
</robot>

Spawn_enitiy error:
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712814841.208330714] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712814841.210351790] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712814841.210528917] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1712814871.288989281] [spawn_entity]: Service %s/spawn_entity unavailable. Was Gazebo started with GazeboRosFactory?
[spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1712814871.290530628] [spawn_entity]: Spawn service failed. Exiting.
[ERROR] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has died [pid 16044, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py -topic robot_description -entity my_bot --ros-args'].
[gzserver-2] AL lib: (EE) ALCpulsePlayback_connectStream: Stream did not get ready: Timeout

launch file:
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():


    # Include the robot_state_publisher launch file, provided by our own package. Force sim time to be enabled
    # !!! MAKE SURE YOU SET THE PACKAGE NAME CORRECTLY !!!

    package_name='autonomous_bot' #<--- CHANGE ME

    rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
                )])
    )
    # twist_mux_params = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','twist_mux.yaml')
    # twist_mux = Node(
    #         package="twist_mux",
    #         executable="twist_mux",
    #         parameters=[twist_mux_params, {'use_sim_time': True}],
    #         remappings=[('/cmd_vel_out','/diff_cont/cmd_vel_unstamped')]
    # )

    gazebo_params_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','gazebo_params.yaml')

    # Include the Gazebo launch file, provided by the gazebo_ros package
    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')]),
                    
             )

    # Run the spawner node from the gazebo_ros package. The entity name doesn't really matter if you only have a single robot.
    spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                        arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                                   '-entity', 'my_bot'],
                        output='screen')

    
    # Code for delaying a node (I haven't tested how effective it is)
    # 
    # First add the below lines to imports
    # from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
    # from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
    #
    # Then add the following below the current diff_drive_spawner
    # delayed_diff_drive_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
    #     event_handler=OnProcessExit(
    #         target_action=spawn_entity,
    #         on_exit=[diff_drive_spawner],
    #     )
    # )
    #
    # Replace the diff_drive_spawner in the final return with delayed_diff_drive_spawner



    # Launch them all!
    return LaunchDescription([
        rsp,
        gazebo,
        spawn_entity,
    ])


Do the gazebo_ros2_control_demos work for you? If yes, then there seems to be some problem with the my_controller.yaml or the controllers you are trying to load. (controller_manager segfaults)

@ChristophFroehlich No, it is not working.

With the same errors? have you installed ros2_control from binaries or compiled from source? Which version have you installed, ros2 pkg xml ros2_control -t version?

@ChristophFroehlich I have install ros2_control  by command  ros-humble-ros2-control ros-humble-ros2-controllers  and ros-humble-gazebo-ros2-control
ros2 pkg xml ros2_control -t version - 2.40.0

have you installed the gazebo_ros2_control_demos?
What is the error if you launch one as described here

@ChristophFroehlich gazebo_ros2_control_demos are working but spawn_entity.py' is not working [spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712814841.208330714] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712814841.210351790] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712814841.210528917] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1712814871.288989281] [spawn_entity]: Service %s/spawn_entity unavailable. Was Gazebo started with GazeboRosFactory?

what do you mean with "demos are working" but spawn_entity is not working? It is part of the demo..

@ChristophFroehlich All ros control demos are working which you mentioned but for my project spawn_entity error is there and also gzserver -slibgazebo_ros_init.so -slibgazebo_ros_factory.so -slibgazebo_ros_force_system.so'].

it seems that there is just a problem with your URDF or launch file, which you haven't provided. Hard to tell, what is inside rsp.launch.py for example.

I deleted Ros2 and reinstalled it. Then, rebuild the workspace again with all packages. This works for me.
